# Query Values from mongo array

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework, pymongo

**I want to query an array for mongo db**

**Sample Data**

In data I have multiple arrays of fields which contains dynamic fields names which are not mandatory and its position will be random. I want to extract a particular title and its value for all the fields.

```
{ 
    "_id" : NumberInt(2), 
    "categories" : [
        {
            "sections" : [
                {
                    "fields" : [
                        {
                            "title" : "Name", 
                            "value" : "ABC"
                        }, 
                        {
                            "title" : "Gender", 
                            "value" : "Female"
                        }, 
                        {
                            "title" : "DOB", 
                            "value" : "2010-03-03T18:30:00.000Z"
                        }, 
                        {
                            "title" : "Email", 
                            "value" : "sample@sample.com"
                        }, 
                        {
                            "title" : "Work", 
                            "value" : [
                                "Business"
                            ]
                        }, 
                        {
                            "title" : "Address", 
                            "value" : "new add"
                        }
                    ]
                }, 
                {
                    "fields" : [
                        {
                            "title" : "FirstJob", 
                            "value" : "new"
                        }, 
                        {
                            "title" : "Achievments", 
                            "value" : "abc"
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
{ 
    "_id" : NumberInt(6), 
    "categories" : [
        {
            "sections" : [
                {
                    "fields" : [
                        {
                            "title" : "Name", 
                            "value" : "Sample"
                        }, 
                        {
                            "title" : "Gender", 
                            "value" : "Male"
                        }, 
                        {
                            "title" : "DOB", 
                            "value" : "2018-10-22T18:30:00.000Z"
                        }, 
                        {
                            "title" : "Email", 
                            "value" : "o@o.com"
                        }, 
                        {
                            "title" : "Work", 
                            "value" : [
                                "Freelancer"
                            ]
                        }, 
                        {
                            "title" : "Address", 
                            "value" : "old add"
                        }
                    ]
                }, 
                {
                    "fields" : [
                        {
                            "title" : "FirstJob", 
                            "value" : "ddds"
                        }, 
                        {
                            "title" : "Achievments", 
                            "value" : "dsdsds"
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

**I want to find every id's email and its value and achievements and its value either using mongo query or pymongo**

**Expected Output**

```
{ 
    "_id" : NumberInt(6), 
    "categories" : [
        {
            "sections" : [
                {
                    "fields" : [

                        {
                             "Email",  : "o@o.com"

                        }
                    ]
                }, 
                {
                    "fields" : [ 
                        {
                          "Achievments" : "dsdsds"
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

**Things I tried Object to array but it is not dynamic**

```
db.collections.aggregate(
{ $arrayToObject: { "$literal": [
   { "categories.sections.fields.title": "email", "categories.sections.fields.value": "sample@sample.com"}
] } }
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Using $elemMatch, we can fetch data of arrays.

```
db.getCollection('transactions').find({"categories.sections.fields": {
  "$elemMatch": {
        "$and": [
            {
                "title": { "$eq": "Email"  }

            },
            {
                "title": { "$eq": "Achievments" }
            }

        ]
    }}})
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply but it did not work it gave me all results containing email and achievements.

Comment: I want only email and achievements from all results.